# Unit test with check testing framework

Tags: c, unit-testing

I have some code where the purpose is the decide if a char is between quotes in an expression. For example, `awk '{print $1}'` has a `{` between quotes.

The function that I want to test is

```
int IBQplain(int pos, char *str, int offset);

int IBQdouble(int pos, char *str, int offset);

int IBQsingle(int pos, char *str, int offset) {
    int escaped = 0;
    for (; str[offset]; ++offset) {
        if (!escaped) {
            switch (str[offset]) {
                case '\\':
                    escaped = 1;
                case '\'':
                    return IBQplain(pos, str, offset + 1);
            }
        } else {
            escaped = 0;
        }
        if (pos == offset) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int IBQdouble(int pos, char *str, int offset) {
    char ch;
    if (pos == offset)
        return 0;  /* Not within quotes */
    int escaped = 0;
    for (ch = str[offset]; ch; ch = str[++offset]) {
        if (!escaped) {
            switch (str[offset]) {
                case '\'':
                    return IBQsingle(pos, str, offset + 1);
                case '"':
                    return IBQdouble(pos, str, offset + 1);
                case '\\':
                    escaped = 1;
            }
        } else {
            escaped = 0;
        }
        if (pos == offset)
            return escaped;  /* Not within quotes, but may be single-escaped */
    }
    return 0; /* FIXME */
}

int IBQplain(int pos, char *str, int offset) {
    char ch;
    if (pos == offset)
        return 0;  /* Not within quotes */
    int escaped = 0;
    for (ch = str[offset]; ch; ch = str[++offset]) {
        if (!escaped) {
            switch (str[offset]) {
                case '\'':
                    return IBQsingle(pos, str, offset + 1);
                case '"':
                    return IBQdouble(pos, str, offset + 1);
                case '\\':
                    escaped = 1;
            }
        } else {
            escaped = 0;
        }
        if (pos == offset)
            return escaped;  /* Not within quotes, but may be single-escaped */
    }
    return 0; /* FIXME */
}


int isBetweenQuotes(int pos, char *str) {
    return IBQplain(pos, str, 0);
}
```

Write the test

```
#include "openshell.h"
#include "errors.h"
#test myQtest
fail_unless(isBetweenQuotes(11, "abc'asdqerfdsdxcvc'xc") == 1, "isBetweenQuotes function borked");
lm */
```

Compile it and run it

```
gcc -Wall -o bquotes-test util.c errors.c bquotes-test.c -lcheck -lsubunit -lrt -pthread -lm^C
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450:~/osh$ ./bquotes-test 
Running suite(s): Core
100%: Checks: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0
```

It seems ok. I make more tests

```
#include "openshell.h"
#include "errors.h"
#test myQtest
fail_unless(isBetweenQuotes(11, "abc'asdqerfdsdxcvc'xc") == 1, "isBetweenQuotes function borked");
fail_unless(isBetweenQuotes(5, "abcasdqerfdsdxcvcxc") == 0, "isBetweenQuotes function borked");
fail_unless(isBetweenQuotes(11, "ab'c'as'dqerfdsdxcvc'xc") == 1, "isBetweenQuotes function borked");
```

Compile and run it

```
checkmk tst_bquotes.check > bquotes-test.c
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450:~/osh$ gcc -Wall -o bquotes-test util.c errors.c bquotes-test.c -lcheck -lsubunit -lrt -pthread -lm
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450:~/osh$ ./bquotes-test 
Running suite(s): Core
100%: Checks: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0
```

Comment: What's the purpose of your code? What problem does it solve?

Comment: @Mast I added the purpose of the code: I have some code where the purpose is the decide if a char is between quotes in an expression. For example, `awk '{print $1}'` has a `{` between quotes.

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot.

Comment: @Mast Yes it solves a rather important problem for me...I must check if certain char are between quotes to be able to parse commands properly. Now I'm learning to write my first unit tests with check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As OP did not explicitly state the review goals, here are some general ideas.

1. Use `const` when referenced data is not changed. Allows for optimizations and defined behavior when the array address passed is `const`.

   ```
   // int IBQplain(int pos, char *str, int offset);
   // int IBQdouble(int pos, char *str, int offset);
   // int IBQsingle(int pos, char *str, int offset);
   int IBQplain(int pos, const char *str, int offset);
   int IBQdouble(int pos, const char *str, int offset);
   int IBQsingle(int pos, const char *str, int offset);
   ```
2. Use `size_t` as the type for array indexes.  `int` maybe insufficient.

   ```
   // int IBQplain(int pos, char *str, int offset);
   int IBQplain(size_t pos, char *str, size_t offset);
   ```
3. As the functions only return 1 of 2 values, consider `_Bool` or `bool`

   ```
   #include <stdbool.h>
   // int IBQplain(size_t pos, char *str, size_t offset);
   bool IBQplain(size_t pos, char *str, size_t offset);
   ```
4. As these functions appear to be stand-alone, suggest more pessimistic range checking:

   ```
   // if (pos == offset)
   if (pos <= offset)
     return 0;  /* Not within quotes */
   ```
5. ... otherwise if the below 3 are only helper functions to `isBetweenQuotes()`, they should be `static`.

   ```
   static int IBQplain(int pos, const char *str, int offset);
   static int IBQdouble(int pos, const char *str, int offset);
   static int IBQsingle(int pos, const char *str, int offset);
   ```
6. Unclear why code accesses the array again instead of `ch`

   ```
   for (ch = str[offset]; ch; ch = str[++offset]) {
       if (!escaped) {
         // switch (str[offset]) {
         switch (ch) {
   ```
7. Expect more test cases that have incomplete `''` and `""` pair combinations, especially onces that begin or end the string.